# How can I get the index of the Nearest Point when I use CGAL::K_neighbor_search to do the Nearest Neighbor Search?

Tags: cgal, nearest-neighbor

I am using CGAL's K_neighbor_search module to do the nearest neighbor search problem. It's nice and easily to use. The example code shows that given a query point, it can find the nearest neighbor point from a set of points as well as the distance. However, I can only get the nearest neighbor point itself. I don't know how to get the index of the point found by the algorithm.
For example, I use the following code,

```
std::list<Point_d> points;
Tree tree(points.begin(), points.end());
Neighbor_search search(tree, query, N);
for(Neighbor_search::iterator it = search.begin(); it != search.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "Point: " << it->first << "\n";
    std::cout << "Distance: " << std::sqrt(it->second) << "\n";
}
```

the result is as follows:

> Point: 222 129 161
>
> Distance: 189.307

But how can I get the index of the result point? As for the reason of this question, I want to get the normal of the nearest neighbor point, so I need to reference the point.
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use indices directly in the kd-tree you can look at [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_searching/index.html#title12).
Points are sorted in an external vector and the kd-tree uses indices to refer to the points internally store.